# Advice on plyr-ing this 'for' loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr, netcdf

Try as I might, I can't quite figure out how to get plyr to work.  Would appreciate any help with this specific example, and bonus points for any explanations of why your example works.

The data is [here](http://www.geog.mcgill.ca/landuse/pub/Data/175crops2000/NetCDF/maize_5min.nc.zip), in case anyone wants to make this example "workable"

Setup:

```
library(ncdf)
library(plyr)
longs = seq.int(from=1,to=4320,by=6)
lats = seq.int(from=1,to=2160,by=6)
blocksize = 6
maize.nc = open.ncdf('maize_5min.nc')
```

This for loop works, but is slow and not parallel:

```
latlongcoords = NULL
for (x in 1:length(longs))  {
for (y in 1:length(lats))   {   
    lat = mean(get.var.ncdf(maize.nc,varid="latitude",start = lats[x],count = blocksize))
    lon = mean(get.var.ncdf(maize.nc,varid="longitude",start = longs[y],count = blocksize))
    rw = c(lat,lon)
    latlongcoords = rbind(latlongcoords,rw)
    }
    #print(x)
    }
save(latlongcoords,file="latlongcoords")
```

I want to do something like this:

```
require(doMC)
registerDoMC(32)
x = seq(1:10)  #shorten it for testing purposes
y = seq(1:10)  #shorten it for testing purposes
makecoords = function(x,y){
    lat = mean(get.var.ncdf(maize.nc,varid="latitude",start = lats[x],count = blocksize))
    lon = mean(get.var.ncdf(maize.nc,varid="longitude",start = longs[y],count = blocksize))
    c(lat,lon)
    }
latlongcoords = NULL
latlongcoords = aaply(.data = cbind(x,y), .margins=2, .fun=makecoords(x,y),.parallel=TRUE)
```

When I run it, I get this error message:

```
Error in get.var.ncdf(maize.nc, varid = "latitude", start = lats[x], count = blocksize) : 
  Error: variable has 1 dims, but start has 10 entries.  They must match!
```

It looks like plyr is passing the whole vector to the function, not the individual values!  Advice for how to make this work, and explanations of why your fix works, are really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to include it.  Its a function that does what the loop does.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think you've to pass `.margin=1` instead of `2` here. That is, if you want to pass the values **by row**, then `.margin = 1`. `x[1]` and `y[1]` are first passed to w. So, we'll access them using `w[1]` and `w[2]` and pass it to your `makecoords` function. I hope this is what you expect. If not, feel free to write under comments as to what's going wrong.

```
latlongcoords <- aaply(cbind(x,y), 1, function(w) 
                 makecoords(w[1], w[2]), .parallel=TRUE)
```

It works fine with `.parallel = FALSE` for me. Can't test `.parallel=TRUE` now.

```
head(latlongcoords)
# X1              1            2
#   1    89.7500025 -179.7499949
#   2    86.7500025 -176.7499949
#   3    83.7500025 -173.7499949
#   4    80.7500025 -170.7499949
#   5    77.7500025 -167.7499949
#   6    74.7500025 -164.7499949
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work:  
'Error in list_to_array(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .drop) : 
  Results must have the same number of dimensions.'

Comment: It works for me on the test example with `.parallel = FALSE`. I'm unable to install `ncdf` on the cluster. Can't test `.parallel = TRUE`. Does it work when you set it to FALSE?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work.  It gives me the following:
`X1       1       2
  1  89.75 -179.75
  2  89.25 -179.25
  3  88.75 -178.75
  4  88.25 -178.25
  5  87.75 -177.75
  6  87.25 -177.25
  7  86.75 -176.75
  8  86.25 -176.25
  9  85.75 -175.75
  10 85.25 -175.25`
A 2x10 input array should give me a 2x100 output array

Comment: `.margin=1` is for row-wise, right. When you do that, each row is passed to your function one by one. This is assigned to `w` in this case which is a vector of 2 elements for your case. So, we need to access w[1] and w[2] as your function takes two arguments separately.